# Why are my villagers attempting to breed (they have the red hearts) but then stop breeding suddenly and gray "angry" particles pop up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I set up a villager breeder and set down 4 beds with 2 villagers in the middle and a carrot farmer supplying them with carrots. The first time both of those villagers bred the breeder worked perfectly fine. After that, however, the gray angry particles popped up every time they would try to breed (they would engage in breeding at a normal pace, just could not actually produce a baby). I even killed the one villager they produced in case it took a bed and even then, the two villagers would not breed anymore. Is there something I have done wrong? This seems odd considering they were only able to breed once and even by eliminating their offspring the villagers could not breed again.

Edit: version is 1.16.4

Comment: @PausePause there's no angry particles in that question, so I believe that is a separate issue

Answer (score 0):

After doing a quick search I saw [two](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/cbuvyu/villagers_not_breeding_and_showing_angry_particles/) [Reddit posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/cjsbjc/villagers_showing_angry_particles_when_breeding/) also noticing the red particles you saw. The solutions to their problems were different, despite the particles being the same. This may mean that the particles are a generic "error" notification when villagers are unable to breed, which is caused by a variety of reasons.

Nonetheless, the solutions to these Reddit posts were to add 3 times as many beds as there are villagers, and to make sure the villagers have at least one full block of space above their heads.